# merge 2 or more png image over base images in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, css, gd

I have base image which is circle with Dashes & another 24 images with single dash highlighted. I want to merge those 24 dashes images in base image with the help of PHP GD. or JS Or CSS.

All images are png images.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the images a class or id:

```
<img class="progress" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThNPg.png"/>
<img class="aboveprogress" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/drRa2.png"/>
<img class="aboveprogress" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpCTF.png"/>
```

In CSS tell the images where to display:

```
.progress {
    position: fixed;
    top: 5px;
    left:5px;
    z-index: 0;
}
.aboveprogress {
    position: fixed;
    top: 5px;
    left:5px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```